# Is there a javascript like operator for increment (++) in python?

Tags: javascript, python

Is there any way to do this javascript code in python syntax:

```
var x = 1;
x++;
```

without:

```
x=1
x=x+1
```

Comment: What's wrong with `x=x+1`?

Comment: Isn’t it easier to find this information on the web instead spending time to ask a question? That’s like sending a regular mail instead of email because you forgot Wi-Fi password

Comment: no, python does not have a unary increment operator

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Javascript `x++` expression has a value (specifically, the value of x after incrementing it) and the Python assignment statements do not. Use the walrus operator `(x:=x+1)` if you need a Python3.8+ assignment expression which has this value.

Answer (score 2):

No, in Python you can only do this:

```
x += 1
```

or in alternative

```
x = x+1
```

Comment: Depending on why you're using it, you may want to look at the enumerate and count methods too.